# Switch function keys on OS X via via command line?

Tags: macos, mac

For a game (WoW) I want to swap cmd and alt key, because I want to bind it as a hotkey modifier. Problem is you can't bind the commandkey so I have to swap the keys in the settings every time I want to play and swap back afterwards.

Is there a way to do this on the commandline so I can craft a script?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html):

```
k=/Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook.app/Contents/Applications/KeyRemap4MacBook_cli.app/Contents/MacOS/KeyRemap4MacBook_cli
$k changed | grep -q ^remap.commandL2optionL= && mode=disable || mode=enable
$k $mode remap.commandL2optionL
$k $mode remap.commandR2optionR
$k $mode remap.optionL2commandL
$k $mode remap.optionrcommandr
```

You could make pressing shift-F1 swap command and option by using a private.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>toggleoptcmd</name>
    <identifier>toggleoptcmd</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE,
    KeyCode::VK_CONFIG_TOGGLE_swapoptcmd</autogen>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>swapoptcmd</name>
    <identifier vk_config="true">swapoptcmd</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

This would swap option and command only when TextEdit is frontmost:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<appdef>
  <appname>TEXTEDIT</appname>
  <equal>com.apple.TextEdit</equal>
</appdef>
  <item>
    <name>swapoptcmdtextedit</name>
    <identifier>swapoptcmdtextedit</identifier>
    <only>TEXTEDIT</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Another option is to use AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell    
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of process "System Preferences"
    click button "Modifier Keys…" of tab group 1
    tell sheet 1
        --tell pop up button 5
        --click
        --click menu item "Apple Wireless Keyboard" of menu 1
        --end tell
        if value of pop up button 1 is "⌘ Command" then
            tell pop up button 1
                click
                click menu item "⌥ Option" of menu 1
            end tell
            tell pop up button 2
                click
                click menu item "⌘ Command" of menu 1
            end tell
        else
            tell pop up button 1
                click
                click menu item "⌘ Command" of menu 1
            end tell
            tell pop up button 2
                click
                click menu item "⌥ Option" of menu 1
            end tell
        end if
        click button "OK"
    end tell
end tell    
quit application "System Preferences"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact do it from the terminal. It's basically insane, though.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Remap capslock to control. Really.
#
# list of keyboards plugged in to this computer
keyboard_ids=$(ioreg -n IOHIDKeyboard -r | grep -E 'VendorID"|ProductID' | awk '{ print $4 }' | paste -s -d'-\n' -)
# check if the keyboards are already remapped
echo $keyboard_ids | xargs -I{} sh -c 'defaults -currentHost read -g "com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.{}-0" | grep "Dst = 2" > /dev/null'
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  # remap the keyboards
  echo $keyboard_ids | xargs -I{} defaults -currentHost write -g "com.apple.keyboard.modifiermapping.{}-0" -array "<dict><key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst</key><integer>2</integer><key>HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc</key><integer>0</integer></dict>"
fi
```

That changes `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/.GlobalPreferences.<machine_identifier>.plist`, and then you can log out and back in or open the Keyboard prefpane to apply the setting.

Comment: This is awesome, but you need to specify -n1 to xargs to make it only take 1 word at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do it via Terminal, but a good work-around would be to create an Automator script do do it for you quickly. The simplest way would be a 'watch me do' block, though they don't look at all polished.

A more complicated way would be using an applescript, either by itself or with an Automator script. However, I'm not sure exactly how you would use the applescript, but I'm sure you could figure it out.

Comment: I did it with the automator. I never used apple script. I think I will look into this when I have time for it.